# Cron: compress log files of the week WITHOUT re-compressing previous one. Oneliner

Tags: shell, cron

I have LOTS of logs and I need to compress them in a weekly basis, this is, every Saturday. I manage to do a oneliner to do that, but I don't want to re-compress the files already compressed. For example:

```
ls  myDir/
test1 test2 test3
```

At saturday of **week 1** I will have:

```
ls myDir/
test1.bz2 test2.bz2 test3.bz2
```

On **week 2**, I would have:

```
ls  myDir/
test1.bz2 test2.bz2 test3.bz2 newTest1 newTest2
```

At Saturday of week 2 I **would like to have**:

```
ls  myDir/
test1.bz2 test2.bz2 test3.bz2 newTest1.bz2 newTest2.bz2
```

This is: the compressed files, but **not re-compress the already compressed files**

This is my crontab oneliner:

```
0 2 * * 6 find /myDir -name "log*" -ctime +7 -exec bzip2 -zv {} \;
This is:
   Find all the log files, 7 days of older and compress them.
   (could be obvious! but I'm a newbie)
```

This only compress the files. But don't know how to do the verification or how to avoid the situation I'm telling. If I try to run the command again it seems that the files compressed are not affected, but I'm not sure if this always will be. I don't want to mess the production server of the company!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
find /myDir -name 'log*' -and -not -name '*.bz2' -ctime +7 -exec bzip2 -zv {} \;
```

Comment: Terrific. Thank you! Mini-question: if I don't put that additional verification I would have problems, in terms of re-compression -didn't happened to me in this case, that's why I'm asking-